# Nested ViewPager not displaying

Tags: android, android-viewpager, nested-views

I am writing an application where used Nested ViewPager. Every Parent ViewPager contain 7 child ViewPager.

It work properly for first parent, but when it reached to next Page it show blank at place of child Viewpager.

Any suggestion here, if it's feasible to use Nested View pager even? and if it is How can I avoid this case?

Parent ViewPager Layout and same as Child Fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:customfont="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/calendarViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and this is Child ViewPager Adapter implementation that I am doing from Parent ViewPager Fragment:

```
private void processDatacardAdapter(View view) {

        childViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.childViewPager);

        childSlidePagerAdapter = new ChildSlidePagerAdapter(parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());

        childViewPager.setAdapter(childSlidePagerAdapter);

        childViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                Utils.showToast(parentActivity, "sds position : " + position);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please post your code here..

Comment: can you please add the code of Parent ViewPager and its Adapter... i think the problem is in parent view pager.

Comment: This post has a nested viewpager. Child viewpager is created inside the fragment of parent viewpager. https://www.journaldev.com/19336/android-nested-viewpager-vertical-viewpager

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change FragmentManager work for me: Change

`new ChildSlidePagerAdapter(parentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());`

by

`new ChildSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me as well. But is there an explanation behind this though?

Comment: I believe it is very clear. Nested pager need it's parent not the grand-parent view.